# Does the expression "was found to be" make sense?

Tags: phrases

In the following sentence, what do you think of saying "was found to perform better"?

*In a study that compared PostGIS with Oracle Spatial, PostGIS  was found to perform better*

It sounds odd to me but I want to say more than just plain "PostGIS performed better"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound odd to me. It's passive voice, but that's not necessarily wrong, and here, it emphasizes that these were your study's findings.